# Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '/'

Tags: php, escaping

This has appeared in past on SO, but I couldn't find an answer that worked for me.

I am getting error in line 64 i.e. `else { $commenter = preg_replace( '(<a )/', '\\1class="url "' , $commenter );}`, the error has something to do with escape character to be introduced. Can anyone give me a pointer what the solution might be?

```
 if ( preg_match( '/]* class=[^>]+>/', $commenter ) ) {$commenter = preg_replace( '(]* class=[\'"]?)', '\\1url ' , $commenter );
    } else { $commenter = preg_replace( '(<a )/', '\\1class="url "' , $commenter );}
    echo $commenter ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the first [delimiter](http://www.php.net/manual/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

```
preg_replace('/(<a )/', '\\1class="url "' , $commenter );
```

should work.

In your current case, PHP assumes `( )` to be the delimiters (which is valid) and `/` to be a [modifier](http://php.net/manual/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) (because it comes after the second delimiter) which is not valid and hence the error "Unknown modifier '/' "